# Android keystore - signed without "alias_name"

Tags: android

Quick question I couldn't find an answer for on Google.

I signed my app and accidentally left the "alias_name" as alias_name.

Does it really matter? (app uploaded to Market fine...)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alias is for the keystore (the thing you use to sign your app). So while it may look strange in your development workflow, the resulting .apk / app does not have any bad contents because of it.